# Get specific string among list of strings that contain same prefix and suffix

Tags: python

I have a list of strings that all start with the the same prefix then a unique number then a suffix. I want the strings that do not contain any suffix.

I've tried filtering by string length but it's messy. Also I cannot include "and not _direct in x" because the suffix will be different each time this program is run. It won't always specifically be "_direct"

```py
list = ['__light_grp1, __light_grp1_direct, __light_grp2, __light_grp2_direct]

for x in list:
    if "__light_grp" in x:
        print x
```

What I'm expecting:

"__light_grp1, __light_grp2"

What I'm getting:

"__light_grp1, __light_grp1_direct, __light_grp2, __light_grp2_direct"

Comment: format your code properly

Comment: Check the ```string``` methods ```startswith()``` and ```endswith()```.

Comment: did you want to delete all groups that doesn't contain _direct as suffix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the prefix will always be the same, you can use that to your advantage. Basically, you know that words with suffixes will always start with an extra underscore.

So you can do this:

```
prefix = "__light_grp"
ref = len(prefix.split("_"))
for x in lst:
    if (len(x.split("_"))) == ref:
        print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like:

```
list1 = ['__light_grp1', '__light_grp1_direct', '__light_grp2', '__light_grp2_direct']
list2=[]
for i in list1:
    if i[-1:].isdigit():
        list2.append(i)
```

Basically what we do here is check for every item in list if its last element is number